# Using powershell,How to export all subsites,lists with list items(Title,ID,Author) of specific site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I want to export hierarchy of site collections in excel like this using powershell.

```
Site Collection - "https://sitename.sharepoint.com"
     Subsite1 - "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/S1"
        List1
           1 (ID)- Item 1(Title) - Created By
           2 (ID)- Item 2(Title) - Created By
        List2
           1 (ID)- Item 1(Title) - Created By
           2 (ID)- Item 2(Title) - Created By
     Subsite2 - "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/S2"
        List11
           1 (ID)- Item 1(Title) - Created By
           2 (ID)- Item 2(Title) - Created By
```

I have to implement this in SharePoint online and have to read site collection from user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online: Get All Lists and Libraries using PowerShell for your reference:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/sharepoint-online-get-all-lists-using-powershell.html

SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Get All Subsites in a Site Collection:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/powershell-to-get-all-subsites-in-sitecollection-sharepoint-online.html